# parsing xml file to csv with dynamic xml structure

Tags: python, xml

I have been working on learning python and currently working on parsing XML file and converting into CSV file. I am able to iterate the XML file but need not sure how to store the column values especially when the XML values are not consistent.
[XML file location](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NNvvuG0bfh96EgJ8fxPmDlvF3NIGsE9-/view?usp=sharing)

Output expected:
[CSV file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7GcH.png)

I have basic python code as of now and need help what I can use to store and print value as per data in correct csv column:

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
file_path = "Candidate.xml"
tree = ET.parse('Candidate.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.tag, root.attrib)
for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

Comment: Give the hierarchical structure of XML, a fully generic solution to create flat CSVs would be a challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a little complicated but doable:

```
#first collect your data:
data = []
rows = root.findall('.//rows')
for row in rows:
    items = [row.attrib['id'],
            row.find('./column[@name="Organization"]'),
            row.find('./column[@name="Location"]'),
            row.find('./column[@name="Candidate.Address"]/Address1[@name="Candidate.ResidentialAddress"]'),
            row.find('./column[@name="Candidate.Address"]/Address1[@name="Candidate.OfficeAddress"]'),
            row.find('./column[@name="Candidate.GivenName"]'),
            row.find('./column[@name="Candidate.Phone"]')]
    
    #insert the data into a line
    line = []
    for item in items:        
        if item is None:
            line.append("")
        else:
            try:
                line.append(item.text.strip())
            except:
                line.append(item.strip())
    data.append(line)

#finally, prepare your csv:
headers = ["id","Organization","Location","ResidentialAddress","OfficeAddress",".GivenName","Phone"]
with open('candidates.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

The output should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Jack for the response this does work as expected but I would like to know how to make it more generic. i dont want to keep dependency on column name. Can we somehow  change following checks to check column names present and store all row.find('./column[@name="Organization"]') and then dynamically build this header accordingly headers = ["id","Organization","Location","ResidentialAddress","OfficeAddress",".GivenName","Phone"]

Comment: @AshishJ Yes, I was actually thinking about this but it's not a simple matter and may not be as generic as you would like it to be. In any case, it's probably best to post it as a separate question, per Stack Overflow policy.